# File Sync issue with Dropbox sync api on ios

Tags: ios, synchronization, dropbox-api

I created a file on ios and add it to dropbox sync api to sync with the dropbox account.

Later when I edit the file, the file I edited did not show on dropbox.  Here is what I did.

I created a file using ios FileManager like this:

```
if(![ABUtil fileExist:FILENAME]) {
    NSString *st = @"This is a Test";
    NSData *file = [st dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *file = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILENAME];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:
                                            contents:file
                                          attributes:nil];
}
```

Then I create a dropbox file for it like this:

```
DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount];
if (account) {
    DBFilesystem *filesystem = [[DBFilesystem alloc] initWithAccount:account];
    [DBFilesystem setSharedFilesystem:filesystem];

    if([ABUtil fileExist:FILENAME]) {
        DBPath *path = [[DBPath root] childPath:FILENAME];
        DBFile *file = [filesystem createFile:path error:nil];

        [file addObserver:self block:^(){
            NSLog(@"FILE CHANGED");
        }];
    }

}
```

Later when I modify the file using on ios like this:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *file = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILENAME];
    NSString *string = @"Tis is a test";

    [string writeToFile:file atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

The file did not change at dropbox directory!!  Please help me how to make the file change sync with the dropbox!!!

Comment: Why do you expect the updated file to sync to Dropbox? You are writing the update to the app's Documents folder, not to Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** I was mistaken. There *is* a method on NSString to write its contents to a file. So that part is presumably working. The next step would be to copy that file into Dropbox.

When you finish modifying the local file, you'll want to call [`writeContentsOfFile`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios#DBFile.writeContentsOfFile%3ashouldSteal%3aerror%3a) to upload that file to Dropbox.

Or you could skip the local file altogether, which is the more common pattern with the Dropbox Sync API. (Take a look at the Notes example that ships with the Sync SDK to see how to edit Dropbox files directly.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  The reason I tested on the txt file because I have a sqlite database file on ios, and the user updates the database all the time, I'd like to sync this database.db file to dropbox.   So do I have to call writeContentsOfFile everytime after the database update or insert?  What about the addObserve to observe the entire app root directory like this: [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] addObserver:self forPathAndChildren:[DBPath root] block:^(){
  NSLog(@"FILE SYSTEM CHANGED");
 }];

Comment: Yes, you'll have to write the file into Dropbox every time it's changed. I don't see how the observer will help... that only observes files in Dropbox.

Comment: The observer is needed so device B knows when device A updates the file.

Comment: Yes, you'll need that (and you'll have to copy files out when they change), but the observer you already have set up should cover that. (`[file addObserver:...]` in the code you shared)

Comment: Ok. So I will have to call writeContentsOfFile every time when I change the local files in order sync with Dropbox account.   I also need to add observer for all the files and directories, right.  What about if device1 adds a file A to DB, and device2 adds a file B to DB, how are they going to sync each other?  and if device1 modify the file C,  how does device2 get the update of file C?

Comment: Hi smarx:  I cannot skip the local files because the app is existing app and already have a lot of local files created by the users on the devices.  I implemented dropbox sync using core api which does not work very well on sync files.  core api always duplicate the files if the file is already on dropbox server.  which makes a big mess for my app.

Comment: This kind of manual syncing (copying files in and out) is going to be very tricky to get right. The Core API and Sync API use the same underlying web API... they're just different interfaces on top, so using the Sync API isn't particularly going to help you to avoid conflicts.

Comment: I see. that is too bad. I wish there is a good way to sync my database file.

Comment: Honestly, trying to sync a database as a single file is fraught with peril. Any time there are two concurrent changes (like when a device is offline), you're going to get a conflict and have no way to resolve it. This is why we built the [Dropbox Datastore API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore).